# jQuery Globalization. Pass currency unit as argument for C format

Tags: javascript, localization, currency-formatting, jquery-globalization

I am setting up a multilingual site that deals with currencies. I want to be able to display correct currency formats based on the selected language. The server side PHP stuff is a doddle. Using a combination of PHPs NumberFormatter and strftime I have been able to format currencies and dates correctly.

There is however a requirement to have the same degree of formatting done client side with javascript.

I have come across Globalization (former jQuery plugin) and it looks quite promising.

If I want to display a dollar value in American English I can do something like this:

```
jQuery.preferCulture("en-US");

// Formatting price
var price = jQuery.format(3899.888, "c");
//Assigning stock price to the control
jQuery("#price").html(price);
```

and this will output:

```
$3,899.89
```

While doing:

```
jQuery.preferCulture("fr-FR");

// Formatting price
var price = jQuery.format(3899.888, "c");
//Assigning stock price to the control
jQuery("#price").html(price);
```

outputs:

```
3 899,89 €
```

which looks perfect. however, I have a need to output multiple currencies. So, if I have 'fr-FR' selected as my preferred culture, how can I output, say, a dollar value like so:

```
3 899,89 $
```

so that the format is French, but the value is American Dollar. I have looked but not found anyway to pass a currency symbol as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [only documented way](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#currency-formatting) to modify the currency symbol in Globalize is to change the `numberFormat.currency.symbol` property of a given culture—in this case, the `fr-FR` culture. This will kind of do what you want, but it’s not a very elegant solution, and you would need to manually build a table of correct symbols for each locale and write another method to swap them out. (n.b. It is possible to pass a third argument to `Globalize.format` with a different locale identifier, but this just formats the number using *that* locale’s cultural settings.) Looking at the [culture definition syntax](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#defining-culture-information), there is simply no provision for displaying different currencies using a given locale.

If you were to look elsewhere, the [dojo/currency](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/currency) module in the Dojo Toolkit does do exactly what you need, using data from the Unicode [Common Locale Data Repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLDR) to determine how to represent various currencies in different locales. So you can set your locale to `fr`, write `currency.format(3899.888, { currency: "USD" })`, and it will output the currency in USD in the correct format for the French locale.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, Not what I wanted to hear, but very detailed and informative none the less. +1 for pointing to the Dojo solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in the end I just replaced the default currency symbol on the output with the symbol I wanted to display.  It's a bit primitive but it keeps the formatting correct for the locale with the currency symbol you want.

```
function formatCurrency(value, format, symbol){
    var formattedValue = Globalize.format(value, format);

    if (typeof symbol === "string") { 
     formattedValue = formattedValue.replace(Globalize.culture().numberFormat.currency.symbol, symbol);
    }

    return formattedValue;
}

document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML = formatCurrency(123.34,"c"); //<-- $123.34
document.getElementById("price2").innerHTML = formatCurrency(123.34,"c","£"); //<-- £123.34
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjJLb/1/)